# How to replace missing row with a specific values in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to generate a report as in the query:

```
select cIDNum,cvisitNo, cgender
from table detail
```

Some records for a visit are not entered into the database and thus missing. Now I want to have the missing rows for the visit amended in the query so that I have it as follows:

```
l256T, 0,F
l256T, 1,F
l256T, 2,F
l256T, 3,F
l256T, 4,F
l256T, 5,F
l256T, 6,F
```

Comment: What does the data look like currently?  Which bits are missing?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: How do you know what is missing? Your question is unclear.

Comment: eg: let say 1256T,2,F was not entered. This possible if the study participant was not seen on a visit day. my report should just show the :1256T,2  to maintain the sequence if visit numbers for each ID Number.

Comment: Read about `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: left join would not do. this is one table.

Comment: No, logically there are two tables - the visits, left joined to the visit days. Depending on what you're actually doing, this can be a real table or e.g. a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
;With cte1 as 
( select * from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) a(n) )
,Cte2 as ( select c1.* from cte1 c1, cte1 c2, cte1 c3)
,numbers as ( select RowN = row_number() over (order by (select null))-1  from cte2 c1, cte2 c2)
Select td.cidNum, RowN as cVisitNo, td.cgender from Numbers n
    Left join tableDetail td
    on n.RowN = td.VisitNo
```